# dualvar Lamda P_Balance....... GAMS

Tags: gams-math

I am writing a bilevel model on GAMS and i am using the EMP tool to solve it. I need the dual variables of a certain equation to be assigned to a variable called lamda which i am using in the upper level problem. Till this stage that's perfectly fine as i use the following command *dualvar Lamda P_Balance* which assigns the dualvariables of the equations P_Balance to Lamda. Both of the variable Lamda and the P_balance equations are defined over set i /1*33/ (Variable Lamda(i) and P_balance(i)). However, i need only Lamda(3), Lamda(22), and Lamda(25) in the upper level objective function. So, i wrote the upper level objective function as follows

```
Prof =e= sum((DG_Inv1, b), (MC(DG_Inv1, b) * Pg(DG_Inv1, b))) - sum((Inv1_N, DG_Inv1, b), Lamda(Inv1_N) * Pg(DG_Inv1, b));
```

such that Inv1_N is a set includes /3, 22, 25/. I have tried writing that equation in different ways, but Unfortunately i always receive the following error:

```
*** JAMS Pre processing failed
***

**** ERRORS/WARNINGS IN EQUATION P_Balance(1)
                    AND VARIABLE Lamda(3)
     1 error(s): dualVAR pair has different domains
     1 error(s): dualVar pair of different size

**** ERRORS/WARNINGS IN EQUATION P_Balance(2)
                    AND VARIABLE Lamda(22)
     1 error(s): dualVAR pair has different domains

**** ERRORS/WARNINGS IN EQUATION P_Balance(3)
                    AND VARIABLE Lamda(25)
     1 error(s): dualVAR pair has different domains
```

If you don't mind, would you please help me in rewriting the Obj function in a way that can only select Lamdas of i = 3, 22, 25 and at the same time the command Dualvar Lamda P_balance is not violated? or how can i assign from the beginning the dual variables of P_balance at i = 3, 22, 25 to Lamda while keeping the objective function as written?

Here is that part of my code:

```
Variable Prof; 
Variable Lamda(i);  
.
.
.
.
ULPObj..
*    Prof =e= sum( (DG_Inv1,b) , (MC(DG_Inv1,b)*Pg(DG_Inv1,b)) ) - sum( (i$(ord(i) and i=ord(Inv_N)), DG_Inv1, b ) , Lamda(i)*Pg(DG_Inv1,b) );
*    Prof =e= sum( (DG_Inv1,b) , (MC(DG_Inv1,b)*Pg(DG_Inv1,b)) ) - sum( (i, DG_Inv1, b )$(i IN (Inv_N)) , Lamda(i)*Pg(DG_Inv1,b) );
*    Prof =e= sum( (DG_Inv1,b) , (MC(DG_Inv1,b)*Pg(DG_Inv1,b)) ) - sum( (Inv1_N,DG_Inv1, b) , Lamda(Inv1_N)*Pg(DG_Inv1,b) );
*     Prof =e= sum((DG_Inv1, b), (MC(DG_Inv1, b) * Pg(DG_Inv1, b)))
*          - sum((i, DG_Inv1, b)$(i IN Inv1_N), Lamda(i) * Pg(DG_Inv1, b));
     Prof =e= sum((DG_Inv1, b), (MC(DG_Inv1, b) * Pg(DG_Inv1, b)))
          - sum((Inv1_N, DG_Inv1, b), Lamda(Inv1_N) * Pg(DG_Inv1, b));
.
.
.
.
P_Balance(i)..
      sum((D,k)$DB(i,D),Pd(D,k)) + sum(j$cx(j,i), Pij(i,j)) -  sum((DG,b)$DGB(i,DG),Pg(DG,b))    =e=  0;
.
.
.
.
.
$onecho > "%emp.info%"
bilevel  X
min Z * Equations
dualvar Lamda P_Balance
$offecho
```

I kindly expect a help in writing the upper level objective function or modifying the dualvar command in a way that to assign only the required dual variables

Comment: Shouldn't that be **lambda** (yes - "b" before "d") - at least that's the correct name for e.g. lambda calculus etc. (or lambda functions and such)

Comment: Hi Marc, thank you for your comment. Lamada is not parameterized in d.